# How do you find the cross sectional area of a Tetrahedron?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, 3d, volume, area

How is vector's related to this question? If so, how can you use the vectors? I understand that its a triangular pyramid. But how can you show the cross sectional area for any generalised height?

Show that the area $A(h)$ of the cross-section at height $h$ above the table is given by $A(h)= (1−\frac{h}{H})^2A, 0 \leq h \leq H$ where $A$ is the area of the base and $H$ is the height of the apex above the base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The square root of the ratio of the bases is proportional to the ratio of the heights of the pyramids:

$\sqrt{\frac{A(h)}{A}} = \frac{H-h}{H}$

I believe you could take over from here...

Comment: I am studying vectors are the moment.. do you know how to put this into vector form?

Comment: How can you prove that the square root of the ratio of the bases is proportional to the ratio of the heights of the pyramid?

Comment: If create the 3D description of the pyramid, you will find that the ratio of the highest is proportional to the ratio to, for example a side of the bases. Since the area is proportional to the square of the sides, than the ratio of the areas of the bases is proportional to the square of the ratio of the highest.